# What do <prog1.pl> and <prog2.pl> do in their while-loop?

Tags: perl

I ran two programmes <prog1.pl> and <prog2.pl>. Now I need to figure out what happens in their while-loop. Help would be greatly appreciated.

prog1.pl

```
my $k = "";
print "running ...\n";
open (IN,"auste-north-1522.txt");
open (OUT,">outfile3.txt");
while (<IN>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/\ <[^i].*[^i]\ >/g) {
        print OUT $_;
     }
}

close (IN);
close (OUT);

print "Press the return/enter key to finish.";
$k = <STDIN>
```

prog2.pl

```
my $k = "";
print "running ...\n";
open (IN,"auste-north-1522.txt");
open (OUT,">outfile4.txt");
while (<IN>) {
    $_ =~ s/(\ <i\ >)|(\ <\ /i\ >)//g;
    print OUT $_ unless ($_ =~ m/\ <.*\ >/g);
}

close (IN);
close (OUT);

print "Press the return/enter key to finish.";
$k = <STDIN>
```

I was told study their scripts but I still struggle to understand.

Comment: Is there some Perl exam going on right now? A veryyyy similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245634/perl-m-g-or-m-g-meaning) was posted 1 hour ago...

Comment: What parts do you not understand? The `<IN>` syntax? What a `s///` is? Or just what's inside the `s///`?  It makes it easirt for everyone if we only explain what's confusing you rather than explainign everything.

Answer (score 3):

`while (<IN>)` is a common way how to shorten

```
while (defined($_ = readline IN))
```

Inside the first loop

```
$_ =~ m/\ <[^i].*[^i]\ >/g
```

matches the topic variable `$_` against a regular expression. The backslashes before spaces aren't needed, same for the `/g`. You can write it as

```
/ <[^i].*[^i] >/
```

Which matches if there's a space, `<`, anything but `i`, then 0 or more of anything but a newline, anything but `i` again, space, and `>`.

For example, these strings match:

```
" <jj >"
" <jXj >"
```

The second loop is left as an exercise for the reader, see [perlsyn](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn), [perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop), [perlre](https://perldoc.pl/perlre).